# Convert a horizontal menu into vertical

Tags: css

I have a horizontal menu that I need to convert to vertical menu (using @media when width is below threshold).

I am working on the menu provided [here](http://insicdesigns.com/demo/css3/exp2/index.html)

However I am just not able to convert the menu into a vertical one. I tried `display:inline;` and `position:relative` but its just not working.

Any help would be appreciated. I have got the relevant code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/T3fuv/).

THanks

Comment: specified link already contain the vertical menu.So whats the problem?

Comment: I want to convert the horizontal menu into vertical using @media in css3. So basically I want the menu to be shown as either a vertical or a horizonatal dynamically based on whether its being opened in mobile or PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what I have understood you what is when the use is on a mobile device you want to make the navigation vertical, if this is the case you can use media queries

eg :`@media (max-width: 600px) {ul.menu li {float: none !important;}}`

you can reffer to http://dabblet.com/gist/11203269 
**note:** there is no need to use important its just to the demo